# .hfc-key-store certificates are created on every access

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm not sure if this is normal behavior or not. Everytime I access the blockchain a new private/public key pair is created and saved in .hfc-key-store. Therefore this folder becomes huge, how do you handle that?   Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?  The Node SDK support loading existing credentials.  The likely cause of this is that you are actually enrolling each time rather than using existing credentials

Comment: thanks for your answer. yes, this was the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Node SDK supports loading existing credentials. The likely cause of this is that you are actually enrolling each time rather than using existing credentials as much of the sample code actually does this for convenience.